# List and manage Azure Resource Locks with Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, for-loop, azure-resource-lock

I am trying to list and loop through Azure Resource Locks of a resource group by using Python SDK.

```
    from azure.mgmt.resource.locks.v2016_09_01.aio import ManagementLockClient
    management_lock_client = ManagementLockClient(credential, subscription.subscription_id)
    locks = management_lock_client.management_locks.list_at_resource_group_level(resource__group_snapshot)
    for lock in locks:
        management_lock_client.management_locks.delete(resource__group_snapshot, lock.name)
```

But here, I get the error:

> **for lock in locks:**
> **TypeError: 'AsyncItemPaged' object is not iterable** .

I have tried different methods like list() and result() but it didn't work. For the moment, I don't want to use directly the REST API but the Python SDK.

Does someone has any idea?

Comment: shouldnt it be: "for lock in management_lock_client.management_locks"   or maybe "for lock in management_lock_client" ?

Comment: no, because I want it to list the locks on the resource group level. list_at_resource_group_level() method returns that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

In my portal, I created three locks at the resource group level.

**Portal:**

[image]

> I want it to list the locks on the resource group level list_at_resource_group_level() method returns that

To list the locks at resource_group_level, you can use the below code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ManagementLockClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id = "subscription id"
resource_group_name = "resourcegrp"

management_lock_client = ManagementLockClient(credential, subscription_id)
locks = management_lock_client.management_locks.list_at_resource_group_level(resource_group_name)

for lock in locks:
    print(lock)
```

**Output:**
[image]

If you need only the name of the locks you can use **`print(lock.name)`** statement.

**Output:**
[image]

If you need to delete the locks at the resource group level you can use the below code.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ManagementLockClient

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
subscription_id = "0151c365-f598-44d6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7"
resource_group_name = "siliconrg"

management_lock_client = ManagementLockClient(credential, subscription_id)
locks = management_lock_client.management_locks.list_at_resource_group_level(resource_group_name)

for lock in locks:
    management_lock_client.management_locks.delete_at_resource_group_level(resource_group_name, lock.name)
print("The locks are deleted at resource group level")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was using the wrong library:  from azure.mgmt.resource.locks.v2016_09_01.aio import ManagementLockClient